# how I can set Xdebug in php.ini for my mini server to seen the error in uniserver?

Tags: php

I tried uniserver portable to get php server run on my computer.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:/UniServer/usr/local/php/extensions/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
```

I have this code run on my three php.ini file (php production,development and php.ini).

I never seen anything on page for error for my mistake code. it's just blank page. someone can help me how I can got it done.

try to access their forum website online but server bandwidth 509 issue.